# How to upload an image from iPhone into ASP.Net web server

Tags: iphone

i want to upload images from my iPhone into asp.net web server. Iam new to iPhone developemnt. Please help...

Comment: This is a difficult question since it will depend on how the server accepts images. How would you normally upload an image form a HTML form? Action, Address etc.

Comment: In the server i created a from with type "Multi/Part" data. And reading the files from the request. But when try to read the file content from the request object the file size seems as zero kb. I am confusing whether the problem is with .net server or with the image uplaod functionin the iPhone?